# How can I list the questions I have upvoted?

Tags: support, profile-page, search

Is there a way to view all the questions which I upvoted or that contain an answer that I upvoted?

Comment: Why "(not favourite)"?

Comment: Because I can see easily them from my profile.

Comment: You can look for all the questions you upvoted. I imagine you considered all of those useful. Mmmmh. Apparently the [votes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes) does not allow to filter by post type.

Comment: In stackoverflow notation I undestand that upvote = useful, favourite= when i click on the star. In my profile, I can see just the questions which I mark with a "star" and not the questions which I simply upvoted.

Comment: `https://{site}/users/{id}?tab=votes&sort=upvote`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your profile contains a [votes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes).

There you can find all the posts (questions and answers) you have [up](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) or [downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote) in the past.